# Regular expressions - How to prevent any space including in the first character of the string

Tags: regex

currently I have this:  `@"(\S)+"` , but it just prevents spaces after any full character, so how can I prevent space in the first character as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make sure there's no whitespace in the string, use this:

```
^\S+$
```

- `^` anchors the match to the beginning of the string.
- `\S+` matches one or more non-whitespace characters.
- `$` anchor the match to the end of the string.

If you're really using the NSRegularExpression class in Apple's Objective-C developer framework, it should look like this:

```
@"^\\S+$"
```

But if (as I suspect) you're using a C# Regex, it should look like this:

```
@"^\S+$"
```

("regex" is the general-purpose tag for regular expressions.  I'll just remove that other tag.)